# For Each function in VB

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am bad at VB and I tried converting the following C# function in VB which landed me with lots of errors... Can someone please help me converting this into VB.

C#

```
foreach (Google.GData.Client.IExtensionElementFactory  property in  googleEvent.ExtensionElements)
        {
            ExtendedProperty customProperty = property as ExtendedProperty;
            if (customProperty != null)
                genericEvent.EventID = customProperty.Value;                
        }
```

My conversion with multiple errors:

```
For Each Google.GData.Client.IExtensionElementFactory property in  googleEvent.ExtensionElements

            ExtendedProperty customProperty = property as ExtendedProperty
            If (customProperty <> null) Then
                genericEvent.EventID = customProperty.Value
            End If

        Next
```

Comment: It would help if you gave us the error messages.

Comment: Too many "me too" answers of the same exact code. Can someone lock this question?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Which will give you:

```
For Each [property] As Google.GData.Client.IExtensionElementFactory In googleEvent.ExtensionElements
    Dim customProperty As ExtendedProperty = TryCast([property], ExtendedProperty)
    If customProperty IsNot Nothing Then
        genericEvent.EventID = customProperty.Value
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

As already posted, you can use an automated tool for such trivial conversions that don't use more advanced language features.

Note however: In VB, `As` is used to declare the **type** of a variable - not a cast, as it is in C#.

Thus

```
For Each property As Google.GData.Client.IExtensionElementFactory In googleEvent.ExtensionElements

    Dim customProperty As ExtendedProperty = TryCast(property, ExtendedProperty)

    If customProperty IsNot Nothing Then
        genericEvent.EventID = customProperty.Value
    End If

Next
```

Comment: yeah ;) However, you used `DirectCast`, which is AFAIR an incorrect translation of C# `as`, as it won't produce `Nothing` for an invalid cast, which `TryCast`/`as` do.

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each elem As Google.GData.Client.IExtensionElementFactory In googleEvent.ExtensionElements
    Dim customProperty As ExtendedProperty = DirectCast(elem, ExtendedProperty)
    If ExtendedProperty IsNot Nothing Then
        genericEvent.EventID = customProperty.Value
    End If
Next
```

Try That

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
For Each property as Google.GData.Client.IExtensionElementFactory In googleEvent.ExtensionElements
     Dim customProperty As ExtendedProperty = CType(property, ExtendedProperty)
     If customerProperty IsNot Nothing Then
          genericEvent.EventID = customProperty.Value
     End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each property As Google.GData.Client.IExtensionElementFactory In googleEvent.ExtensionElements

    Dim customProperty As ExtendedProperty = TryCast(property, ExtendedProperty)

    If customProperty IsNot Nothing Then

        genericEvent.EventID = customProperty.Value

    End If

Next
```

One of the keys to VB.NET is that it is extremely verbose. Whenever a type is defined, it's generally using "name `As` type" . Similarly, `null` is `Nothing` in VB.NET and you do not use the equals operator to compare it in VB.NET. You use `Is` and `IsNot`.

Finally, `as` casts, or upon failure, it returns `null` in C#. In VB.NET, you use `TryCast` (rather than `DirectCast`).

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close. The main issue is your variable declarations.

in VB, declarations are almost reverse of C#.

I haven't tested it or anything, but the following code should work.

```
For Each [property] As Google.GData.Client.IExtensionElementFactory In googleEvent.ExtensionElements
    Dim customProperty as ExtendedProperty = [property]
    If customProperty IsNot Nothing Then
        genericEvent.EventID = customProperty.Value
    End If
Next
```